# Sentiment Analysis using senti_classifier and NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, wordnet

I'm not doing something right -- By the looks of the error i'm getting i think i'm missing some data. I have all the prerequisites intalled for sentiment_classifier (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentiment_classifier/0.7) which are nltk, numpy, and sentiwordnet. Here's my code - a quick example from the docs i'm trying to get working.

```
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
sentences = ['The movie was the worst movie', 'It was the worst acting by the actors']
pos_score, neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores(sentences)
print pos_score, neg_score
```

and here's the error message i'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/beef/sciencefair2017/sentiment.py", line 1, in <module>
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/senti_classifier/senti_classifier.py", line 227, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1178, in resource_stream
self, resource_name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1454, in get_resource_stream
return io.BytesIO(self.get_resource_string(manager, resource_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1457, in get_resource_string
return self._get(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1535, in _get
return self.loader.get_data(path)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error: 'senti_classifier/data/SentiWn.p'
```

what's the issue and how can i get it working? Any advice, even if only a suggestion and not an actual solution is greatly appreciated. I've already tried various versions of all the packages and I've looked through some of the docs to no avail.

Comment: I don't think might be the problem, but could you try to remove the extra space in `by  the actors` to `by the actors` (one space between "by" and "the")?

Comment: @fedepad just edited it -- surprised i didn't notice it myself! that stuff usually really bugs me.

Comment: I will write in an answer if it works...but I'm not sure that's the problem. I'm looking the code from the library to see that. Let me know.

Comment: Ok, I do not think that's the problem from the code. It looks like a problem in loading the data folder, specifically senti_classifier/data/SentiWn.p.

Comment: Is that file in some place?

Comment: no it isn't -- i can't figure out what it is or where i'm supposed to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: I didn't install the full package - i originally used pip but i had to install it like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier
cd sentiment_classifier
python setup.py install
```

works beautifully now.

Comment: Hello - I am having a similar problem. I have run python setup.py install in powershell, I have NLTK, NumPy. I have downloaded 'sentiment_classifier-0.5.tar.gz', unzipped and pasted the folder in my directory and I get the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\AC\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\senti_classifier\\data\\SentiWn.p'. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I know it has file not found, but I can see it in my directory. The data file is blank. Assuming that might have something to do with it, but I can't confirm

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
import inspect
all_functions = inspect.getmembers(senti_classifier, inspect.isfunction)
all_functions
```

Out:

```
[]
```

No functions in senti_classifier module.