# ImportError when trying to execute command "from senti_classifier import senti_classifier"

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

I'm pretty sure that I've correctly installed the sentiment_classifier package on python. I have to use the package on one of my codes. The problem is that the import command is throwing an error. This is what shows up in my command prompt.

> > > from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "build\bdist.win32\egg\senti_classifier\senti_classifier.py", line 229, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named collections

However when i execute the command "import collections" no error is thrown. I've only recently started learning python and I'm relatively new to it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

PS the solution from [Sentiment Analysis using senti_classifier and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795476/sentiment-analysis-using-senti-classifier-and-nltk) is not working for me.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions installed apart from Python 2.7 ?

Comment: I don't believe so. Running "Python -v" on my command prompt shows a bunch of lines and then "Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"