# NLTK | Sentiment Classifier | Issues with Install

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am having trouble installing the `sentiment_classifier`.

What I have currently done:

1. `pip install sentiment_classifier`
2. `python setup.py install`
3. Downloaded `sentiment_classifier-0.5.tar.gz`
4. Placed the package into my directory

Error in shell:

1. `pip install sentiment_classifier`:

`Requirement already satisfied: sentiment_classifier in c:\users\ac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

`Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\ac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentiment_classifier)`

`Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\users\ac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentiment_classifier)`

`Requirement already satisfied: argparse in c:\users\ac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sentiment_classifie
)`

2. `python setup.py install` - C:\Users\AC\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

When I call it in Jupyter Notebook:

`from senti_classifier import senti_classifier`

I get:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\AC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\senti_classifier\data\SentiWn.p'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Docs I've been referring to:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentiment_classifier
- [Sentiment Analysis using senti_classifier and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795476/sentiment-analysis-using-senti-classifier-and-nltk)
- https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier
- http://pythonhosted.org/sentiment_classifier/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The output from `pip install` is not an error, it simply tells you it didn't have to download these packages because they were already installed. Do you find that you cannot actually use the component?

Comment: `can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`sounds like you are running it in the wrong directory. Where is `setup.py` and what happens if you run the command in that directory?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify the points I have asked about in the previous comments.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/sentiment_classifier/#comment-3354778112 seems to be about the same problem.

Comment: I can't use the component. It just returns that error message. In Jupyter, that's definitely the error message I get (it might be truncated but it doesn't show me anything else). Setup is: "C:\Users\AC\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sentiment_classifier-0.5\setup.py" and when I go to run it, a block box pops up for a second, then nothing else.

Comment: Try with `py.exe` instead of `python.exe` if you are a Windows victim.

Comment: Haha, Yes Windows victim. Sorry, where and what am I changing? If you mean running `py setup.py install` in powershell, I have done this but the same error pops up

Comment: `py` is a wrapper which sets up some things for your depraved environment so you can run Python from the command line. I was imagining it would also cause any output to spill into your current terminal instead of opening a new `cmd` window, but perhaps that is not actually the case (or you are not using a `cmd` terminal to type in these commands).

Comment: But anyway, the anwer you already received seems to echo my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521208/nltk-sentiment-classifier-issues-with-install?noredirect=1#comment84037102_48521208)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing some files needed for it to work and no those files aren't downloaded when you install the package using `pip`, you can download the repository for the library from https://github.com/kevincobain2000/sentiment_classifier and then copy paste the files inside the '/src/senti_classifier/data/' into your library's directory which is 'C:\Users\AC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\senti_classifier\data' directory.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you @tripleee for all your help too! It's very much appreciated. For anyone else having similar issues, follow the above steps. Works

Comment: I have followed the above steps, but I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'collections\r'